# Load data into HIVE table

Tags: hive

My data format is:

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
```

when I try to load data into Hive 3rd column is reading from file .

I created table as follows:

```
hive> create table movies(mid int,mname string,gn string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '::'
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as TEXTFILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> create table movies(mid int,mname string,gn array<string>)
      row format delimited
      fields terminated by '::'
      collection items terminated by '|'
      lines terminated by '\n'
      stored as TEXTFILE;
```

Now you can load your dataset.

Comment: 1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama

Comment: I have written as per your question dataset

Comment: Check first: Try to change the delimiter from `::` to `:`

Answer (score 0):

if the table wont read the data try changing the fields delimiter with the relevant unicode of '::'.